# Rmysql query does not return the correct values?

Tags: mysql, sql, r, rmysql

I have a query in r, using rmysql package :

```
sql.query = paste0("SELECT * FROM performance_db.pcTab WHERE 
                       fk_ID_calc = (SELECT ID_calc FROM performance_db.calculationTab WHERE
                       turbine_model = '",input$t1,"' AND 
                       op_mode = '",input$t2,"' AND 
                       date_entered ='",input$t3,"')
                       AND sensor = 'P_el'"
  )
    spc = fetch(dbSendQuery(conn, sql.query), n = -1)
```

this return a table :

```
head(spc)
  ID_pc voltage_side sensor Air_density v2.5 v3  v4  v5  v6   v7   v8   v9  v10  v11  v12  v13  v14  v15  v16  v17  v18  v19
1     1            0   P_el       1.225    0 44 184 404 721 1165 1686 2107 2272 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300
2     2            0   P_el       1.000   NA 33 155 346 622 1010 1486 1967 2224 2286 2294 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300
3     3            0   P_el       1.030   NA 35 161 358 642 1041 1529 1999 2235 2291 2297 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300
4     4            0   P_el       1.060   NA 37 167 369 661 1072 1571 2036 2249 2295 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300
5     5            0   P_el       1.090   NA 39 173 381 681 1103 1612 2060 2256 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300
6     6            0   P_el       1.120   NA 42 178 392 701 1134 1649 2080 2263 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300
```

I would like to add additional filter on Air_density like :

```
sql.query = paste0("SELECT * FROM performance_db.pcTab WHERE 
                       fk_ID_calc = (SELECT ID_calc FROM performance_db.calculationTab WHERE
                       turbine_model = '",input$t1,"' AND 
                       op_mode = '",input$t2,"' AND 
                       date_entered ='",input$t3,"')
                       AND sensor = 'P_el' AND Air_density = 1"
  )
```

This is return just one row contain the information for Air_density = 1 :

```
ID_pc voltage_side sensor Air_density v2.5 v3  v4  v5  v6   v7   v8   v9  v10  v11  v12  v13  v14  v15  v16  v17  v18  v19
1     2            0   P_el           1   NA 33 155 346 622 1010 1486 1967 2224 2286 2294 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300 2300
```

But when I try to filter base on other Air_densities It does not return anything. Like if in above mentioned query I put `AND Air_density = 1.225` :

```
head(spc)
 [1] ID_pc        voltage_side sensor       Air_density  v2.5         v3           v4           v5           v6          
[10] v7           v8           v9           v10          v11          v12          v13          v14          v15         
[19] v16          v17          v18          v19
```

I have no idea why it is happening !!!

Comment: Why are you comparing (apparent) decimals to string values?

Comment: Yes you should write "AND Air_density = 1.225" as HoneyBadger said.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, It does not change anything if I do like : `AND Air_density = 1.225`, it returns the same values

Comment: Is `Air_density` of type `float`?

Comment: @dns_nx , Yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` data types are not precise.

If you save the value `1.225` it can be saved as `1.22500001`.
And when you try to query all data with the value `1.225`, it won't find it, because it is saved as `1.22500001`.

You should better use datatypes `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`
or try to `CAST` the `FLOAT` values as `DECIMAL` like this:

```
CAST(Air_density as DECIMAL(10,3))
```

This is from the docs of MySQL:

> 11.2.3 Floating-Point Types (Approximate Value) - FLOAT, DOUBLE
>
> The FLOAT and DOUBLE types represent approximate numeric data values.
>   MySQL uses four bytes for single-precision values and eight bytes for
>   double-precision values.
>
> For FLOAT, the SQL standard permits an optional specification of the
>   precision (but not the range of the exponent) in bits following the
>   keyword FLOAT in parentheses. MySQL also supports this optional
>   precision specification, but the precision value is used only to
>   determine storage size. A precision from 0 to 23 results in a 4-byte
>   single-precision FLOAT column. A precision from 24 to 53 results in an
>   8-byte double-precision DOUBLE column.
>
> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE
>   PRECISION(M,D). Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to
>   M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point.
>   For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999
>   when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you
>   insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is
>   999.0001.
>
> Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact
>   values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to
>   problems. They are also subject to platform or implementation
>   dependencies. For more information, see Section B.5.4.8, “Problems
>   with Floating-Point Values”
>
> For maximum portability, code requiring storage of approximate numeric
>   data values should use FLOAT or DOUBLE PRECISION with no specification
>   of precision or number of digits.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html

This link should help you, too:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html